# Programmatically terminate ffmpeg child process on Raspberry Pi

Tags: ffmpeg, raspberry-pi

Is it possible to cleanly terminate ffmpeg when it's running as a child process under Linux (specifically on a Raspberry Pi 4B)? I have a .NET Core 3.1 application which spawns ffmepg with the following command, which should encode an h.264 stream to an MP4 file:

```
ffmpeg -framerate 24 -i - -b:v 2500k -c copy video.mp4
```

After some arbitrary period of time I want to terminate ffmpeg, but everything I try is either ignored or causes ffmpeg to exit immediately -- it never writes the MOOV chunk to the end of the MP4 file, which results in a corrupted file that cannot be played. I realize this chunk can take awhile to generate, and I've tried leaving the process alone for up to 60 seconds, which is far longer than h.264 to MP4 encoding requires interactively on the same device. For the record, I know how to create a "fragmented" MP4 which is mostly playable (using the `-movflags` switch and others), but I'm trying to generate a correct MP4.

I've tried sending a <kbd>Q</kbd> key with or without various CR+LF combos, which I've seen mentioned in similar questions, but I think that's a Windows-only thing.

I've tried every Unix signal as well as combinations of two signals. I saw somewhere (I think the ffmpeg site itself) that `SIGINT` should be sent twice, but that does nothing. In another SO post, somebody suggested sending `SIGQUIT` which also does nothing. Interestingly, sending `SIGINT` followed by `SIGQUIT` is the only combination that actually terminates the process, but it ends immediately with the following output:

```
Error writing trailer of /media/ramdisk/video.mp4: Immediate exit requested
frame=  236 fps= 29 q=-1.0 Lsize=   28928kB time=00:00:09.79 bitrate=24201.9kbits/s speed= 1.2x
video:29167kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: unknown
Exiting normally, received signal 2.
```

I've tried a long delay between the two, nothing happens until the `SIGQUIT` at which point it responds as shown above. Oddly, sometimes it says `received signal 3` instead of 2.

There has to be some trick I'm missing.

Comment: How are you issuing the `SIG*`?

Comment: Using the `Mono.Posix.NETStandard` package.